# Unity3D: When the enemy (clones) are hit, the original prefab enemy takes damage and not the clones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The clones spawn with an EnemyHealth script where their health parameters are set. Within in this script is a function called TakeDamage(). My only guess is that I'm not explicitly defining which enemy needs to have it's health drained within TakeDamage() but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around that because each clone has its own health and TakeDamage() is called from my PlayerAttack script when the weapon collides with the enemy, so I was assuming it would only happen to the colliding enemy. But I guess I need a defined way for TakeDamage() to only affect the enemy that's involved with the collision.

I'm self taught so I apologize if this is simple or a poor question, I've searched all over the place for several days now so I hope someone can help!

EnemyHealth Script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int enemyMaxHealth = 100;
    public int enemyCurrentHealth;
    public HealthBar enemyHealthBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyCurrentHealth = enemyMaxHealth;
        enemyHealthBar.SetMaxHealth(enemyMaxHealth);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void TakeDamage()
    {
        enemyCurrentHealth -= 25;
        enemyHealthBar.SetHealth(enemyCurrentHealth);
        if (enemyCurrentHealth == 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            //needs death animations
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerAttack Script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EnemyHealth enemyHealth;
    public Animator animator;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;
    public bool allowDamage = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            clickAttack();
        }
    }

    private void AnimationCheck()
    {
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Stab"))
        {
            allowDamage = true;
        }
        else
        {
            allowDamage = false;
        }
    }
    private void clickAttack()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Attacking");
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            AnimationCheck();
            if (allowDamage == true)
            {
                enemyHealth.TakeDamage();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of Unity Scene:
[image]

Clone marked in blue is the one being hit, enemy marked in yellow is the original that's taking damage when other enemies are being hit.

Comment: I'm guessing you assigned the original (not cloned) enemy as the value of `PlayerAttack.enemyHealth` in the Unity Inspector.  In `OnCollisionEnter`, you're always damaging that specific enemy, regardless of which enemy you actually hit.  You need to figure out which enemy is actually being hit, and call `TakeDamage` on that enemy instead.  You can do that by using the value of `Collision.gameObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason only one enemy is taking damage is because you are referencing one enemies health component.  Whatever enemy you assign in the inspector to your `enemyHealth` variable is the one that will take damage.

Remove the enemyHealth variable from your PlayerAttack class.

Inside of the collision function, you will get the enemyHealth from the object that you collided with.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        AnimationCheck();

        if (allowDamage)
        {
            var enemyHealth = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
            if (enemyHealth)
            {
                enemyHealth.TakeDamage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can potentially get rid of the CompareTag line if only enemies will have the EnemyHealth script (which it sounds like is the case).  Then you only need to check if the gameObject you collided with has that script to know it is an enemy.

Comment: Hmm thank you!!! This sounds like it will solve my problem. I'm following perfectly, I was having so much trouble getting my head around it. I'll mark as complete once I get the chance to test it out, I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: Yep that worked! I haven't had much practice with setting a variable to an event like that to access other scripts. That's super useful and I have a feeling I'll be doing it a lot. Thanks again!